# What's the meaning of 私たち三人? Does it make sense?

Tags: grammar, translation

What's the meaning of 私たち三人? Does that make sense in japanese?
I found the translation "the three of us" on Google Translate. However, I want to know if that make sense in japanese. If not, What would be the best translation for "the three of us"?

E.g.: In Spanish the direct trasnlation using Google Translate would be "nosotros tres" and in Portuguese "nós os três". The Spanish translation is ok, it would work. But for Portuguese I guess the best translation would be "nós três", since "nós os três" doesn't make sense in Portuguese.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「私{わたし}たち三人{さんにん}」 makes perfect sense.  In fact, it is probably the most common way of saying "the three of us" in Japanese.

Since　Japanese has many pronouns for "we" as I hope you know, you will also be seeing/hearing:

・「われわれ三人」

・「オレたち三人」

・「ボクたち三人」

・「アタシたち三人」

, etc.

Comment: I'm really new at Japanese, so I might be missing something simple. But why did you put those three and four symbols above the ones I've asked the question?

Comment: @dekio They are called [furigana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furigana) and are used for explaining pronounciation. They are often seen in texts meant for people not fluent in reading Japanese (especially kanji), like
 manga for children, or text books for foreigners. It's also used when
 you do something non-standard. For instance, most people would understand「何人だった」as "how many people (were there)", reading「何人」as「なんにん」. So if you instead want to use the same kanji to refer to the nationality of the people, and not their number, you'd write「何人{なにじん}だった」.